# Error "failed to compile testmain package" while running godog in a project outside GOPATH that uses the go modules

Tags: go, automated-tests, cucumber

Using godog I am able to run feature file successfully. Now when I create module using "go mod init mytest.com/automation"; and try to run feature file using godog getting below error:

failed to compile testmain package: exit status 2 - output: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build685806736\b001_testmain.go:5:2: can't find import: "mytest.com/automation/C_/Users//sample_automation_golang/src/features"

I saw similar issue being reported in past but that is marked resolved now: https://github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/issues/136

Can someone help with this error?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: not yet, actually left this, once again I will try with my new project structure

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue, did you find a fix for this ?

Comment: I solved this issue by moving my project outside of gopath